# Lines in web layout for some resolutions

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I have a problem with the layout I'm creating- problem being that in certain resolutions (or if you zoom in) you can see where the outlining of the div boxes are.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:
[image: expected behaviour]

Here's what it looks like at some resolutions (or zoomed in):

[image: observed behaviour]

If you need to see the website, it's [here](http://www.sada-design.com/manny/), though obviously it's not finished yet. You might immediately see the problem based on your resolution, if not you could zoom in or change your monitors resolution.

I would imagine this is a common problem with an easy solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what browser are you using? in firefox 6 they are not visible at any zoom level. it may just be a problem with how that browser renders the page.

Comment: @Jake223: I can see lines if I zoom in Chrome (but not if I don't zoom).

Comment: Interesting, just tested in Firefox and you are right. I've tested the page in Chromes and IE- as well as the browser on my HP Touchpad, and Android phone (in which you can hardly see them on a smaller screen) but yeah it appears every browser I've tested except for Firefox will show these lines.

Comment: also, Opera seems to render them correctly. I have checked chrome, and see what you are talking about, but have no idea. good luck getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `#righthand` to have a `float:left`, the vertical line at the right disappears.

```
#righthand {
    width: 368px;
    height: 373px;
    background: url("../img/right.png");
    float: right;  // CHANGE TO LEFT
}
```

And if you change your `#tp` to `height:248px`, the other horizontal line disappears.

```
#tp {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 249px;  //CHANGE TO 248px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have enough time to look at the site before it was taken down but I think it could be as simple as setting

background: transparent url(imgsrc) no-repeat left top;

that shorthand for the background image in css will lock in the spot.  Other than that I would make sure you have

margin: 0;
padding: 0;

so that you can specify the exact width and make sure the cuts that are made are done to a grid so that when you slice the image you have an exact width.